# Make Like button in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, jsx-a11y

I wan't to make the only selected button change not all in the same time when i clicke on it

I've created this function which contains a Boolean state and the toggle it

```
 const [like, setLike] = useState(false);
 
  const handleLike=()=>{
    setLike(!like)
    console.log(like);
  }
```

and called it here iside the map

```
 return (
    <Grid container spacing={1} px="4%" width='100%' >
      {CardData.map((e, idx) => (
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              alignItems: "center",
              padding: 0,
              border: "1px solid #e0e0e07a",
              position: "relative",
              borderRadius: "1.5rem",
              width: "94%",
              boxShadow: "5px 5px 46px -46px #000000",
            }}
            mb={5}
            key={idx}
          >
            <Box width='100%' >
              
              <Box position="absolute" top=".4rem" right=".8rem">
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="fingerprint"
                  color="default"
                  sx={{
                    zIndex: "4",
                    bgcolor: "#4b4d4eb2",
                    width: "2rem",
                    padding: "4px",
                  }}
                  onClick={(e)=>handleLike(e)}
                >
                {like?<FavoriteIcon sx={{ width: ".8em", color: "#fff" }} />: <FavoriteBorderIcon sx={{ width: ".8em", color: "#fff" }} />}
                  
                  
                </IconButton>
              </Box>
              </Box>
            </Box>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You need one `like` value in state _for each element of the array_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make your `like` state into an array of likes:

```js
 const [likes, setLikes] = useState([]);
 
  const handleLike=(idx)=>{
    const newLikes = [...likes];
    newLikes[idx] = !newLikes[idx];
    setLikes(newLikes);
  }
```

Then, make sure to operate on the correct item in the array:

```
 return (
    <Grid container spacing={1} px="4%" width='100%' >
      {CardData.map((e, idx) => (
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              alignItems: "center",
              padding: 0,
              border: "1px solid #e0e0e07a",
              position: "relative",
              borderRadius: "1.5rem",
              width: "94%",
              boxShadow: "5px 5px 46px -46px #000000",
            }}
            mb={5}
            key={idx}
          >
            <Box width='100%' >
              
              <Box position="absolute" top=".4rem" right=".8rem">
                <IconButton
                  aria-label="fingerprint"
                  color="default"
                  sx={{
                    zIndex: "4",
                    bgcolor: "#4b4d4eb2",
                    width: "2rem",
                    padding: "4px",
                  }}
                  onClick={(e) => handleLike(idx)}
                >
                {likes[idx] ? <FavoriteIcon sx={{ width: ".8em", color: "#fff" }} />: <FavoriteBorderIcon sx={{ width: ".8em", color: "#fff" }} />}
                  
                  
                </IconButton>
              </Box>
              </Box>
            </Box>
</Grid>
```

Importantly, this will only work if elements are in consistent positions in the array. If they could get moved around, then use some other unique key to identify the correct item to like.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a like useState for each Box. You can do something like this:

```js
const Child = (props) => {
    const [like, setLike] = useState(false);
     
    const handleLike= () => {
       setLike(!like)
       console.log(like);
     };

    return (
        /* What renders inside the Box */
    )
};

const Parent = () => {
    return (
        {CardData.map((e, idx) => (
            <Child key={idx} props={props}>
        )}
    )
}
```

Comment: This is the same as I did and still make all like button changes not the selected one

Comment: Can you show me full code via jsfiddle or something please